# Почему селектор * не перебивает селектор h1

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Здравстуйте, есть такая разметка:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    h1 {
      margin: 10px;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>    
  <div>
    <h1>Example</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос такой: почему **margin: 0** селекторa * не перебевает **margin: 10px** селектора **h1**, ведь у селектора * больший приоритет (2), чем у **h1** (1)?

**P.S** таблица приоритетов https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: лучше почитайте эту статью http://css.yoksel.ru/specifity/

Comment: Обратный вариант — универсальный селектор *. Он не имеет веса: 0,0,0,0.

Comment: По вашей ссылке нет никакой таблицы приоритетов.